# how to make a dynamic text show the correct sentence in react when deleting a component (custom html element)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, upon deleting a component, I want to make a dynamic sentence shows the correct sentence like this in app.js:

```
 let awesomePhrase = '';
    if (!this.state.showPersons) {
      awesomePhrase = 'Nobody is here, it seems :/';
    }
    if (this.state.showPersons && this.state.persons.length === 2) {
      awesomePhrase = "All aboard :D";
    }
    if (!this.state.persons.filter(p => p.id === 1)) {
      awesomePhrase = "Where's Matin?!";
    }
    if (!this.state.persons.filter(p => p.id === 2)) {
      awesomePhrase = "Where's Mobin?!";
    }
```

It doesn't show any of the sentence when I delete id 1 or id 2.That is, neither "where's Matin?!" nor "Where's Mobin?!".
But the two first sentences work fine.

---

(EDIT: every piece of code below is within app.js, the main file)

For deleting:

```
deleteHandler = index => {
    const persons = [...this.state.persons].filter(
      person => person.id !== index
    );
    this.setState({ persons });
  };
```

The State:

```
state = {
    persons: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Matin', age: 27 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Mobin', age: 26 }
    ],
    showPersons: false,
    ...
};
```

The component within the render of the class:

```
 {this.state.persons.map(person => {
            return (
              <Person
                key={person.id}
                name={person.name}
                age={person.age}
                click={() => this.deleteHandler(person.id)}
              />
            );
  })}
```

the part of render where dynamic text is used:

```
return (
  <div>
  ...
   <h2>{awesomePhrase}</h2>
  ...
  </div>
)
```

Comment: where do you set `showPersons`?

Comment: @JuniusL. it is set in State and used in Render to toggle showing the components. It works fine. I seem to make it respond by using "find" instead of "filter". Actually I think I got it now. I will update the question.

Comment: it would be helpful to state which code comes from which component.

Comment: Everything presented is all within app.js, the main file.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: In my humble opinion, so far I managed to make it work. So yeah, I guess. But I hope whether there is some room for improvement or proper of way of handling it. EDIT: I will move it that "edit" in question as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the `filter` function. Filter will return an empty array if no elements passed the test, and in Javascript, an empty array is not a falsy value.

The condition `!this.state.persons.filter(p => p.id === 2)` will always be false.

The proper function to use in this situation is `Array.some`, which return a boolean value depends on the result of the test function.

Be aware of the return type and the falsiness / truthiness in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround

instead of `filter` I used `find`, and tried to check them within deleteHandler method. Also added an independent `awesomePhrase` to State.
So:

```
  deleteHandler = index => {
    const persons = [...this.state.persons].filter(
      person => person.id !== index
    );

    if (persons.length === 0) {
      this.setState({ awesomePhrase: 'where did they all gone?' });
    }

    if (persons.find(p => p.name === 'Matin')) {
      this.setState({ awesomePhrase: 'Where is Mobin?' });
    }
    if (persons.find(p => p.name === 'Mobin')) {
      this.setState({ awesomePhrase: 'Where is Matin?' });
    }

    this.setState({ persons });
  };
```

```
  state = {
    persons: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Matin', age: 27 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Mobin', age: 26 }
    ],
    ...,
    showPersons: false,
    mobin: true,
    awesomePhrase: ''
  };
```

```
 return (
      <div className="App">
        ...
        <h2>{this.state.awesomePhrase || awesomePhrase}</h2>
        ...
      </div>
    );
```

I'd welcome any suggestion to help improve my code further or correct it properly. I just made it work now.